# .htaccess sub links not effecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos7

I want to make dynamic links to seo friendly links so i had created a htaccess rules as follow

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/category/([a-z0-9_-]+)?$  products.php?category=$1  [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products/uicat/([a-z0-9_-]+)?$  products.php?uicat=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (index|about|products) $1.php [L]
```

I'm running centos 7 with apache and PHP 7.3 and i have enabled Allowoverride ALL and options:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes MultiViews
```

If i rename rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^testproducts/uicat/([a-z0-9_-]+)?$  products.php?uicat=$1  [NC,L]
```

it does work so i don't know what i'm doing wrong and i'm not really comfortable with these htaccess rules so all helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes MultiViews
> ```

You need to remove `MultiViews` from the `Options` directive.

By enabling `MultiViews` mod_negotiation will trigger an internal subrequest for `products.php` (having requested `/products`) - before your mod_rewrite directives are able to process the request, so will not include the URL parameters.

You probably want to remove `Indexes` as well. And do you really need `ExecCGI` and `Includes`?

---

*Aside:*

Do you need all the filesystem checks? Could a request of the form `/products/category/something` map to a file or directory? Bear in mind that your regex already excludes a file extension.

> ```
> RewriteRule (index|about|products) $1.php [L]
> ```

This is matching `index`, `about` or `products` *anywhere* in the requested URL-path - this is too general, since you are rewriting to a file in the current directory.